# Toast.makeText from resource string

Tags: android, toast, android-resources

I have a class named MyPrimaryClass, this class has a button witch when pressed, creates an Intent with the class myClassForResult.

I use this to start it:

```
startActivityForResult(myIntentOfMyClassForResult, ACTIVITY_EDIT_BTEXT);
```

Both MyPrimaryClass, and myClassForResult extends Activity.

So, when I call Toast.makeText within the myClassForResult, with the text parameter of R.string.my_resource_string, it gives me Force Close!

I have tried this:

```
Context c = myClassForResult.this;
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c,
    c.getResources().getString(R.string.my_resource_string),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Also this: **c = getApplicationContext()**

Also this: **c = getBaseContext()**

Also this:

```
Context c = MyPrimaryClass.this;
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c,
    R.string.my_resource_string,
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

If I use an inline string, like "My toast Text!", it works. But i need to get a string from the resources.

**-Problem solved:**

To solve the problem I changed the duration of the Toast to Toast.LENGTH_LONG

The string **R.string.my_resource_string** value is "The title is empty"

When I change its value to "The title", it worked properly, so I guess the string was too long for the Toast.LENGTH_SHORT duration.

But when i change the duration to **Toast.LENGTH_LONG**, I could use the long string.

```
Context c = MyPrimaryClass.this;
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c,
    R.string.my_resource_string,
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

Comment: post the logcat error on the force close.

Comment: this is the logcat error:

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f04000a

Comment: Can you explain the significance of why are you are using the two classes like that?

Comment: Cause one class is a list of items, the secondary class is for editing those items...

Comment: Do not write answer in body of question, better to create new answer and accept it :)

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't answer myself, cause i'm new to stackoverflow, it does not allow me to do that. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to note:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c,
    c.getResources().getString(R.string.my_resource_string),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();
```

Can be simplified into:

```
Toast.makeText(c,
    c.getResources().getString(R.string.my_resource_string),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This saves you an object reference that you do not need.

One thing you need to understand is that whenever you reference you R in your package (not android.R.) you will have access to your resources as long as you have Context.

**Update**

After realizing what you are using this for I would **recommend that you
change your approach**, while this is in fact possible, your approach isn't ideal for something so simple.

The method startActivityForResult(xx) is typically when you want to start an application that is outside of your package for a result.

**For instance**: if I wanted to retrieve a barcode from a product, then I'd start an Intent to that barcode class, *indirectly* through an action. Then I'd retrieve the data through using onActivityResult(xx).

it makes **No Sense** to do this for your own classes.

Comment: my answer is provided in the bottom.

Comment: I kinda knew it, but i'm learning Android programming yet, so I tried to post a simple code, avoiding to do some noob error :)

Comment: Thanks @JoxTraex, but how can i retrieve a result from a class of my own, not using startActivityForResult?

Comment: Depends on the data. What is it? @DMF

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just maintain that integer array in your current class? or store it perhaps in a database?

Comment: The secondary Class that is called makes the integer array, then return it to the primary class. I won't create a database table only to solve a problem with a simple toast text..

Comment: Consider making the integer array in your current class then.

Comment: @JoxTraex Look what just happened, the string that I'm trying to get from the resource is: R.string.empty_title. I changed it to any other string resource like R.string.testing_title, it worked!

Comment: Something could have gone wrong with your R or it did not update properly. This happens all the time, the trick is to double check your reference and then cleaning your project.

Comment: @JoxTraex the value of R.string.empty_title is "The title is empty". I changed it to "The title", it worked!
 So the problem is the text length. What the hell...

Comment: Really? Android Force Closes your app, if you give a long (4 words) string, and don't give enough time for the user to see it?!

Comment: why not just use `R.string.text` in the string field, it works with me

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.my_resource_string), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Comment: the **this** is invalid, cause the code is inside a **View.OnClickListener**

Comment: Get a reference to MyPrimaryClass and use MyPrimaryClass.getString(R.string.my_resources_string)

Comment: I did this: 
Context c = MyPrimaryClass.this;
then c.getString(R.string.my_resources_string)

Comment: yea, you must use the context in general not this

Answer (score 2):

@dilipkaklotar Answered correctly but a few changes needs to be done:

this is how it worked for me

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.message),
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

the getResources has no parenthesis ().
and at the end is .show(); not toShow().

but it's correct. so thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getResources.getString(R.string.imgval), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).toShow();
```