# Toast not showing properly in my activity

Tags: android, toast

i can't figure why my toast dosen't show up anyone can help ... i started today to learn app development but i don't understand what is the problem...
My app works without any error , this is a work exercise from my programming book

```
    package com.example.geoquiz;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;

    public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
        private Button but1;
        private Button but2;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
            but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
            but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            but2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);

            but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, R.string.incorect_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/question_text" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/true_button"
        android:id ="@+id/true_button" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/false_button"
        android:id ="@+id/false_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">GeoQuiz</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name ="question_text">Gabriel este un baiat destept ?</string>
    <string name ="true_button">TRUE</string>
    <string name ="false_button">FALSE</string>
    <string name ="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name ="correct_toast">RaspunsCorect</string>
    <string name ="incorect_toast">RaspunsIncorect</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: can you also attach the layout please!

Comment: If you recently edited the resources, clean and rebuild just in case so that the `onClick`s are registered on the correct components.

Comment: Are the buttons: true_button and false_button been clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Go into your xml and on the button you want to make the toast text add

```
 android:onClick="ToastButtonClicked" />
```

^ into it.

Then use the below code for making the toast text.

```
}
public void ToastButtonClicked(View view)
{
Toast.makeText(this,R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: @user2979239 This will work. I've used it myself. Please accept answer if it was useful.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

```
Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Instead of using activity context, i am using Application Context. Check if this works.

Comment: This really shouldn't have any effect either way.

Comment: I am very well aware of the fact that using Activity context and application context might not have any impact. But the code displayed had no error. So, i guess, it is good to give  a try.

Answer (score -1):

replace this

```
Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,R.string.correct_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with

`Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,"Correct Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show`();

may be it will help you

Comment: This should have no effect, they are just two different constructors for the same Toast. One accepts a resourceID and the other a String

Comment: if you want to use resource replace toast text part("Correct Toast") with QuizActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.correct_toast)

Comment: That is what user2979239 is already doing. I was stating that your suggestion changes nothing, only which constructor was used.

Comment: Technically Illusionist's comment is correct but the `Toast` should still appear (with an integer value as that's what R.whatever returns).

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152709/toast-maketext-from-resource-string) just refer to this link